# Java memory management for java docs and comments

Tags: java, memory-management

Is the commented part of the code in a java program stored in memory? If it is stored, in which part of the memory is it stored?

Comment: If it was it would be detrimental to write good comments.

Comment: Comments rot and should be discouraged (yes, exceptions exist). Write readable code instead.

Comment: So does that mean it is not stored anywhere in memory?

Comment: Does it matter? What do you want to do with comments?

Comment: Comments take up space in *my* memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The commented part of the code exists only in the source code.

All comments are removed when you compile the code.

According to [**java language specification**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.7):

> - `/* text */`
>   A traditional comment: all the text from the ASCII characters /* to the ASCII characters */ is **ignored** (as in C and C++).
> - `// text`
>   An end-of-line comment: all the text from the ASCII characters // to the end of the line is **ignored** (as in C++).